# Relationship between two angles in nonlinear system

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I am trying to analyze the kinematics of a robotic wrist. The geometry looks like this:

I want to find the relationship between the input angle $\alpha$ and the output angle $\theta$. The figure depicts the position of the pieces for two different timesteps to show the evolution over time. The subscript $0$ depicts the initial position while the subscript $1$ depicts the position after a random timestep. $l$, $\beta_0$, $p$ and $r$ are constant. The input to the system is the angle $\alpha$ which creates a linear motion in the shape of $p \cdot sin\big(\frac{\alpha}{4}\big)$. $\alpha$ can be positive or negative. The linear motion moves the initial lower end of $l$ from $0$ to $p \cdot sin\big(\frac{\alpha}{4}\big)$ creating a change in the angle $\beta$ and lifting the bar with length $r$ by an angle $\theta$.
 So far through basic geometry I have found that:

$x_0 = l \cdot sin(\beta_0)$

$y_0 = l \cdot cos(\beta_0)$

$x_1 = l \cdot sin(\beta_1) = r(1-cos(\theta)) + x_0$

$y_1 = p \cdot sin\Big(\frac{\alpha}{4}\Big) + l \cdot cos(\beta_1)$

This directly gives the possibility to map the input to the output angle by:

$r \cdot sin(\theta) = l \cdot (cos(\beta_1)-cos(\beta_0)) +p\cdot sin\Big(\frac{\alpha}{4}\Big)$

Now the problematic is that I can't find a relationship for the evolution of $\beta_1$.
Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Where are - $\alpha$? p? $\alpha_m$?

Comment: Are  you fixing  $r+x_0$?

Comment: @Moti thanks for your reply. I edited the problem description, I hope it is more clear now. $\alpha_m$ and $\alpha$ are the same thing. And $r + x_0$ is indeed fixed and known. All constants and the initial position are known.

Comment: I do not see the values in the diagram. It is not clear what is given. Are you looking for $\theta& and $\beta$ that will keep the straight line Ballscrew?

Comment: Are you seeking $\theta$  and   $\beta$   that will keep Ballscrew? You did not show on the diagram the values as I asked. Input and Output need to be clear.

Comment: @Moti the input is a linear displacement of the ball screw. The ball screw moves linearly according to the rotation of a DC Motor. For every full rotation of the motor $\alpha = 360\deg$, the ball screw moves $p$. The output to the system is the angle $\theta$. I am trying to find the relationship between input angle $\alpha$ and output angle $\theta$. The given values are: $l$,$\beta_0$, $p$ and $r$.

Comment: Is for $\alpha=0$ the result $\theta=0$?

Comment: $x_0$ seems to be fixed - are you using this?

Comment: Same with $\beta_0$. Replace $\beta_1$ with the fixed values and $\theta$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$r×cos\theta + l×sin\beta_1 = r + l×sin\beta_0$

$r×sin\theta + l×cos\beta_0 = l×cos\beta_1 + p×sin{(\alpha / 4)}$

$l×sin\beta_1 = r + l×sin\beta_0 - r×cos\theta$

$l×cos\beta_1 = r×sin\theta + l×cos\beta_0 - p×sin{(\alpha / 4)}$

I believe from here you can take over - take the squares and sum. On the left side you will be left with $l^2$, thus $\beta_1$ disappears.

Now you can solve the relation as desired.

Comment: thanks a lot! I was missing the squaring part.